# Make a checker if it exist:

Tags: python

Hi I have realy simple task I have to build a checker to chect if in existing list is a URL what we have here is a code:

```
    def read(file):
        f =open(file, "r") 
        return f.readlines()
    def append(file, data):
        f = open(file, "")
        f.write(data)

list = ["https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vFjXKOXdg","https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iyozS5UCbBs"]
readed = read("test.txt")
len = len(readed)


for i in range(len):
    if list[1] == readed[i]:
        print("Breaked")
    else:
        append("test.txt", list[1])
        print("Added")
```

a output shold be a text breakde if a test.txt is a URL and if this URL is new we never before used it: Do something and append a nwe url to test.txt. Error is a haen I ruun this code url whit onw has been used befoor e is append to test.txt and append has been prinded.

Comment: Please proof read your question. You have numerous spelling and grammar errors which makes it very hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Don't use the names of [built-ins](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) as variables, like `len` or `list`. This shadows the built-in, potentially leading to unexpected behavior. It also makes the code difficult to read.

Comment: you could learn to use `for item in readed:`.And you sould check `if item in list:` but first you have to remeber that `readlines()` gives lines with `'\n"` at the end so it is good to do `item = item.strip()` to remove `'\n"` and all spaces on both sides.

Comment: if you want append to file then you should open with `"a"`

Answer (score 0):

You have few mistakes/problems in this code.

- `file`, `len`, `list` are reserved words so don't use them as variables
- `readlines()` gives lines with `\n` at the end so you have to use `.strip()` to remove it. It also removes spaces if they are at both sides.
- you should learn to use `for item in data` instead of `for i in range(len(data))`
- to check elements on list you can do `item in data` (but you check `list[1]` so you compare only with one element on list)
- you should close file when you write because system may keep data in buffer and it may save on disk only when you close file
- you should add new url also to list from file so if you will have the same url few times on list with urls then it will skip duplicated urls.
- to append to file you have to use `"a"` and you have to add `\n` because `write()` doesn't add `\n` automatically.

BTW: because words `url` and `urls` (`line` and `lines`) are very similar - so it is easy to make mistake - so I added prefix `all_` to make it safer.

```
def read(filename):
    f = open(filename) 
    data = f.readlines()
    f.close()

    data = [x.strip() for x in data]  # remove `\n` and spaces

    return data

    # if lines don't have spaces then you could use (without `strip()`)
    # data = f.read().split('\n') 

def append(filename, data):
    f = open(filename, "a")
    f.write(data + "\n")
    f.close()   # if you don't close then it may not write data (because system may keep it in buffer)

all_urls = [
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vFjXKOXdg",
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iyozS5UCbBs"
]

all_lines = read("test.txt")

for url in all_urls:
    
    if url in all_lines:
        print("Breaked:", url)
    else:
        append("test.txt", url)
        all_lines.append(url)
        print("Added:", url)
```

---

**BTW:**

Other method is to use `set()` for this

```
new_urls = set(all_urls) - set(all_lines)
```

and later you need only `for`-loop to write `new_urls`

```
for url in new_urls:
    append("text.txt", url)
```

or using one string

```
all_urls_in_one_string = "\n".join(new_urls)
append("text.txt", all_urls_in_one_string)
```